# Errata for Lyons's DSP book

Tags: reference-request

After reading the comments$^1$ and looking through various texts, I am going to use *Understanding Digital Signal Processing* for my self-study (Oppenheim & Wilsky was my 2nd choice). I'm 99% sure that a solutions manual doesn't exist. But does anyone know where I can find the errata for the 3rd edition?

I saw an old thread where the author, Dr. Richard Lyons offered to send it to someone so I can email him personally, assuming I can find his address. Before going that route, I figured that someone here may have it. Thanks.

$^1$${\tiny\textrm{ Thanks to all for past threads where this was discussed and great advice given.}}$

Comment: Richard is right here at DSP SE. He might actually answer your question.

Comment: Oppenheim and Schaefer is more DSP than the book with Wilsky which is more Linear systems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This blog post](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1094.php) by Richard Lyons contains the links to the Errata for all editions of Understanding DSP

[International 3rd Edition Errata here.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/embeddedrelated/user/14446/errata%203rd%20ed.%20international%20version_91701.pdf)

Comment: When did he get a PhD?

Comment: Oops my bad, edited to remove the Dr.

Comment: He might have gotten one in the last 10 years, I just didn’t know

Comment: Hi  Stanley: Thanks for heads up on difference between Oppenheim text and DSP. I tend to consider it all one topic but that's good to know.  As far as Richard Lyons, I I don't know if he has one or not but I don't think it really matters either way. Anyone heard the other acronyms  for B.S, M.S and Ph.D ??? I believe that  a reasonably intelligent, passionate high school graduate could study one field for some period of time ( in time units of years of course )  and have as good  a background as anyone else. Finally,  as anyone with a Ph.D, already knows, not all Ph.D's are created equal !!!!

Comment: @itismeghasyam: thanks for link. I got it. 12 pages so I'm glad that I asked.